# Fixing English text with no spaces

Tags: text, scripting

I have a lot of lines of English text with mostly no spaces between the words.  The text is normal English from 19th century historical records.  I can look at the text and add spaces, but it is very time consuming, not to mention boring.  Is there a "simple" script or program that could work out where to put the spaces?  For some definition of "simple"?  Clearly it would need a dictionary.  I would prefer a script language I could adjust a bit and hopefully it would run on linux/BSD/MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is (close to) impossible. You need something that can understand the meaning of the text.

Remember the old joke about expertsexchange.com, the domain name of Stack Overflow's "competitor", Experts Exchange … or is it Expert Sex Change? You cannot correctly place the spaces without knowing and understanding the context. Note that both have the same grammatical function, so even grammatical analysis cannot tell you which is correct.

There is nothing "simple" about this, you are in territory that could earn you a degree in Artificial Intelligence and Natural Language Processing if you get it right. At least it will be publishable in a reputable top-tier scientific journal.